# Amadeus API error : "code":32171,"title":"MANDATORY DATA MISSING

Tags: php, php-curl, amadeus

I'm trying to create an application for multi city flight search via Amadeus API but there is an error.

This is my code in PHP:

```
$str=' 

{
"originDestinations": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "originLocationCode": "BCN",
        "destinationLocationCode": "MAD",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2023-07-09",
            "time": "10:00:00"
        },
        "arrivalDateTimeRange":{
        "date": "2023-07-10",
         "time": "10:00:00" 
        }
    },
            {
        "id": "2",
        "originLocationCode": "MAD",
        "destinationLocationCode": "ATH",
        "departureDateTimeRange": {
            "date": "2023-07-11",
            "time": "10:00:00"
        }
        ,
        "arrivalDateTimeRange":{
        "date": "2023-07-12",
         "time": "10:00:00" 
        }
    }
],
"travelers": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "travelerType": "ADULT",
        "fareOptions": [
            "STANDARD"
        ]
    },
    {
            "id": "2",
        "travelerType": "HELD_INFANT",
        "associatedAdultId": "1",
        "fareOptions": [
            "STANDARD"
         ]
     }
  ],
    "sources": [
    "GDS"
    ]
  }



';

$arr=json_decode($str,true);



$fanal_arrr=array(

'getFlightOffersBody'=>$arr,

'X-HTTP-Method-Override'=>'GET'

 );
```

`$fanal_arrr` is an argument that pass to a function for post to API,
but API response is an error :

> "code":32171,"title":"MANDATORY DATA MISSING

What is my mistake?

I tried with Amadeus guide and please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about PHP, but i had the same error with python request. If i had sent request with parameters in separate dictionary

```
requests.get('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations',headers=headers_token, params=params)
```

it showed me this error, but when i tried with data in the URL it worked -

```
requests.get('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=LIS&destinationLocationCode=CDG&departureDate=2023-11-14&adults=1&max=2', headers=headers_token)
```

Hope it helps :)